# countif in excel based on column header

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

How to count TtlA, TtlB and TtlC base on column header? Thanks

```
 |TtlA |TtlB | TtlC | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C |
 |  3  |  2  |  2   | x | x |   | x |   | x | x | x | x |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in E2 for a vertical count,

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($A:$C, 0, MATCH(RIGHT(E$1, 1), $A$1:$C$1, 0)), "X")
```

Fill right.

[image: COUNTIF_HEADER]

Use this formula in A2 for a horizontal count.

```
=COUNTIFS($D1:$L1,RIGHT(A1,1),$D2:$L2,"X")
```

Fill right.

[image: COUNTIFs_HEADER]

Comment: thank for your reply, but my question is, i want to count with row not column.

Answer (score 1):

```
|  A  |  B  |  C   | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
-------------------------------------------------------
|TtlA |TtlB | TtlC | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C |
|  3  |  2  |  2   | x | x |   | x |   | x | x | x | x |
```

Formula for Cell A2:

```
=COUNTIFS(D2,"x")+COUNTIF(G2,"x")+COUNTIF(J2,"x")
```

Fill this formula to the right to cell C2

Comment: Nice approach to the stagger issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SUMPRODUCT() function. If you setup your sheet like I did then this formula works like a gem. The RIGHT() function was meant to be dynamic so long as you title each column the same, otherwise it can be replaced with static values like, "A", "B" or "C". (Have to watch those "$" refs!)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$1:$L$1=RIGHT(A$1,1))*($D2:$L2="X"))
```

[Screen capture: Excel 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XwN3.png)